# What is the difference between server.port and local.server.port in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

Why are there two names for the port ?

```
server.port=..
```

and

```
 local.server.port
```

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`server.port` is a way to define a value for the tomcat port of your service. It is used in "application.properties" file. If you do not fix this property, the port 8080 is chosen by default.

`local.server.port` is used to recover the value of the running port. It is used in the code like that:

```
@Value("${local.server.port}")
int runningPort;
```

or like that too:

```
@LocalServerPort
int runningPort;
```

Comment: But shouldn't the running port be the same as the tomcat port?

Comment: Sometimes, you want to use a random port like that : `@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
  public class MyTest {`

Comment: If I use by 
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

environment.getProperty("server.port"); still I am getting the port number, So is this using this?

Comment: the `local.server.port` is to be used for testing purposes only; The reason why you have two environment variables for getting the server port is because `server.port` and `local.server.port` may differ! If you set `server.port=0` in your *.properties file then at runtime resolving the `server.port` will be equal to 0 and `local.server.port`will be equal to a randomly allocated port, i.e. 32245.